# SSIS Multiple flat files into tables with Parent Child

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

This is my tables in SQL Server:

```
Table: Customer (CustNum is the PK and auto increments)

CustNum  Firstname  Lastname
123      Bob        Smith
456      John       Paton
789      Fred       Bloggs

Table: Job  (CustNum is the FK, JobNum is the PK and auto increments)

JobNum  CustNum   Item     Desc
852      123      ABCDE    Widgets
654      456      WERT     More Widgets
987      789      QWE      Mouse mat
```

I then have data coming from two csv's in the below format

```
Table: Customer 

Firstname  Lastname
Bob        Smith
John       Paton
Fred       Bloggs

Table: Job

Item     Desc
ABCDE    Widgets
WERT     More Widgets
QWE      Mouse mat
```

I need to import the customers then the jobs into SQL tables but maintain referential integrity.  When the Job record is created, it needs to lookup for the correct CustNum - how do I do this?  I have found many examples doing this from one CS file, but not from multiple csv's.  Also, there is no reliable key to tie the job rows to the customer table - I don't think I will be able to use the SSIS lookup - will I?

Comment: Seems that `CustNum` and `JobNum` are generated when loaded and not present at CSV. Which field from CSV data is used as a FK from Job into Customer?

Comment: If there is no key to connect them, you cannot rely on anything! It's not a question of SSIS Lookups anymore. :) How do you know which customer is related to which job, when you think of it?

Comment: mmmmm at the moment it has a MS Access front end and that seems to create the child records and inserts the cust num into the Job table, but I now need to auto import via CSV

Comment: @Michael you would need to either manage yourself that part, including the generation of child records or have control over it. You simply cannot know from this data, how will they ever be connected.

Comment: thats what I was thinking.  what about a time stamp?

Comment: You really need to specify how to deduce the relation from both CSVs. As far as I can see, there's no relation in the CSVs, so you can''t import it with referential integrity in SQL server. What do you mean with this: `(CustNum is the FK, JobNum is the PK and auto increments)` when referring to the CSVs? As you're describing them, they don't have either of those fields.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  It's a business rules question.   We can't answer it.

Comment: @TabAlleman yes I think you are correct.  I'm going back to the drawing board on this, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SSIS Package to feed your data base.

the package will look like it

[image: Main Package]

[image]

[image]
Result Customer

```
CustNum     Firstname  Lastname
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Bob        Smith
2           Fred       Bloggs
3           John       Paton
```

Result

```
JobNum      CustNum     Item       Desc
----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1           ABCDE      Widgets
2           2           QWE        Mouse mat
3           3           WERT       More Widgets
```

How to do it:

**Main task:**

1. Add a DTS to Customer
2. Add a DTS to Job
3. Create the flow (green arrow) from Customer to Job

**Customer DTS**

4. Add a connection to Customer File
5. Add a connection to Customer SQL
6. Sort Both outputs by Firstname, Lastname
7. Configure the merge join task like the image 
   [image]
8. Insert and configure the conditional Split with one output called "new" and expression `ISNULL(CustNum)`
9. Insert to the Customer table

**Job DTS**

10. Insert a connection to Job file
11. Insert a connection to Customer table
12. Sort both outputs by Firstname, Lastname
13. Configure the join like the image: [image]
14. Insert a connection to Job table
15. Sort both by CustNum, Item
16. Insert and configure the conditional Split with one output called "new" and expression `ISNULL(JobNum)`
17. Insert to the Job table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the source data so it appears in 1 CSV file as opposed to being in 2.  I was then able to use the SQL Lookup function in SSIS and it now works.  Thanks for all those who posted.